# MySQL: Grant Read-Only DB Access for one DB and Create/Drop Access for other DBs

Tags: mysql, permissions

Within MySQL, is it possible to provide a user read-only access to an existing database, but allow the user to create or drop any new databases?

I know it is possible to grant privileges via matching the database name (e.g. by prefix or suffix), but what would be the proper syntax for the first statement below:

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON 'NOT(readonly_db_name)' ...;
GRANT SELECT ON 'readonly_db_name' ...;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  Instead use the following as a general way to provide *limited* actions.

Here's how to "grant" things to the user indirectly.  Create a Stored Procedure with "security definer" and be "root" when you define it.  In the SP, first check that the user is not trying to touch `mysql`, `information_schema`, or the readonly db.  Then proceed to do the `CREATE` or `DROP`.

This can obviously be extended to a variety of actions.  You should probably have one SP per action -- one for `CreateDb('dbname')`, one for `DropDb('dbname')`, and whatever else you might need.

Then train the users to use

```
CALL CreateDb('...');
```

instead of

```
CREATE DATABASE ...;
```

Note: you might need extra parameters for what should be added to the creation, such as `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`.  Or you could assert more control by not giving the user a choice.

Comment: You can probably limit the permissions `GRANTed` to the users so that they cannot do `CREATE DATABASE`, but can create a database via `CALL CreateDb`.